# Python use tor in requests not get cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, tor, socks

i run tor proxy and set 127.0.0.1:9050 to requests
this work for content or status_code.

but not get cookies!

```
import requests 

req = requests.session()
data = req.get('https://google.com', proxies = {
    'https' : 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
})

print(data.status_code)
print(data.cookies)
```

Comment: you tried to fake User-Agent in headers ?

Comment: not working in req.post